# Intent receiving in deep-linked-activity

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking, android-task

I have some problems with proper task stack and bringing to front during deep-linking implementations... I have an `Activity` declared like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.ArticleSingleActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="standard">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http"
            android:host="site.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/article" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

It has `launchMode="standard"` and no parent, because this `Activity` can be launched from many places in app: native buttons or from `WebView`'s. Even on bottom of almost every instance there are placed related articles, so it might call itself (new instance) and every article should appear in new "window"

And now: when my app is running in background and is visible in app manager deep-linking fires `ArticleSingleActivity` on top of other activities without a problem. Intent contains these flags:

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND
```

When app isn't in back stack (lets say removed by user) `ArticleSingleActivity` is launched without brought_to_front flag and everything starts like usual, but I've found small improper behaviour. When I navigate to another `ArticleSingleActivity` (e.g. from related on bottom or to any other `Activity` from side menu), then press home and try to open same deep-linked url then apps is just bring to front. It doesn't show linked article, but `Activity` which was on top when app was "homed". Also breakpoints aren't firing in `onCreate`, `onActivityReenter` or even `onNewIntent`. In my opinion system "remebers" that it have in back stack launched `Acticity` matching this url so it just brings to front whole app, but not proper `Activity` from the stack (no bring_to_front flag like above).

What can I do with this behaviour when I can't even set custom flags for this `Intent` delivered by system or do any `Intent` check in `onCreate` because it isn't called at all in any alive `Activity` on the stack?